# How to change size of arrowheads in MetaUML

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I am doing my UML diagrams with MetaUML, but I need to adjust the size of the arrowheads for some associations to look right (they need to be smaller in size). Is there any option to adjust the size of the arrorheads?

I've read something about `widthA` and `widthB` in the metauml manual, but it doesn't really help because it doesn't tell you how and asking google didn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

In my tool when you click on the association link you have property options such as Link tickness, colors etc...
Did you trick to click on the link with the left mouse button and then click with the right button to open the property tab ?

Comment: What tool for MetaUML? MetaUML are files that need to be compiled first. Never heard of any UI for it. Could you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

Well as you can compile things I would look at the source code.  The line thickness must be set there.

Or look http://www.ntg.nl/maps/33/12.pdf as it talks about font etc, can't quite figure it out in 5 minutes as I have never used metaUml, and my latex is fuzzy.  Example below, from the PDF seems promising.

> PictureInfoCopy.iBig(iPict);
> iBig.left := iBig.right := 20;
> iBig.top := 10;
> iBig.bottom := 1;
> iBig.boxed := 1;
> iBig.ignoreNegativeBase := 1;
> iBig.iFont.name := defaultfont;
> iBig.iFont.scale := 3;

At least I tried and it might send you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default arrowhead size by modifying variables `defaultRelationHeadWidth` and `defaultRelationHeadHeight` in file `metauml_class_relations.mp`.